# Wordpress cronjob is not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

i have problem with cronjob not functionaly work with excect time, I have given in code.

for example: **i have set it run after every 5 min but it runs uneven time.**

Please Help me with this,

I'm new on wordpress.

```
function my_cron_schedules($schedules){

     if(!isset($schedules["five_min"])){
        $schedules["five_min"] = array(
            'interval' => 5*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 5 minutes'));
    }

    return $schedules;
}

add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_schedules');

wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'my_schedule_hook_5min');

wp_schedule_event(time(), 'five_min', 'my_schedule_hook_5min');

add_action('my_schedule_hook_5min', 'wi_create_backup');

function wi_create_backup(){

    global $wpdb;

    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'check_cron';

    $data=array('text' =>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

    $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data);

    if (wp_mkdir_p('C:\wamp64\www\Bakery\test\5')) {
      echo 'It worked! Now look for a directory named "5".';
    } 
}
```

Comment: your wordpress site has enough visitors? wordpress cron based on visitors and if a website ha not enough visitors it dows bot work properly.

Comment: wp-cron will only trigger every five minutes whilst there are continuous http requests to your site.  Every time a page loads, it checks to see if there is anything in the cron that needs to be run.  If nobody visits your site for an hour, it will just run the cron that it missed an hour ago.  The only way to guarantee a cron runs every 5 minutes is to manually run wp-cron.php from the system crontab

Comment: Yea, WordPress did fail with the `cron_schedule` name here confusing it for cronjobs.